# How to compare date and time using comparison operator in c++

Tags: c++, date, time

I have a string read in and it is separated to year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond. I want to be able to compare two different date/ time stamps. Ex. Check if hour on lhs is larger then hr on rhs. and then continue to check months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. So far I have and idea of what I'm trying to do just having a hard time putting it together. If anyone has any ideas that would be awesome. Ps. this is NOT a homework assignment, I'm in the process of building an application, while learning c++.

```
ClassName operator < (ClassName &lhs, ClassName &rhs);
```

above is function.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're changing the arguments for whatever crazy reason, they should be `const`.

Comment: Shouldn't this return a `bool`?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 4):

Make it a freestanding function:

```
friend bool operator < (const ClassName &lhs, const ClassName &rhs);
```

Note the changes:

- Freestanding, because this function treats both the operands equally, it does not modify either.
- `const` parameters, because a sane comparison implementation should not modify its operands.
- return `bool`, because a comparison should ideally return a `bool`, no?
- `friend`, because a well designed class will usually have these data members `private`.

The implementation should simply do a comparison of the data members as per the algorithm you mention and return the `bool` result.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case you should check on the individual members determining which object is "bigger". When comparing, `bool` as return-type should be better and make your arguments `const` as not to change them in the function:

```
bool operator < (const ClassName &lhs, const ClassName &rhs){
    if(lhs.hour > rhs.hour)
       return true;
    return false;
}
```

See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading) for some input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using boost library then use the [date/time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library.

Otherwise you can use the [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) and convert the times into UNIX times and then the comparison is simply a comparison of two numbers.

Comment: Im not using boost library but if i was your suggestion would work thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a bunch of if statements:

```
if(lhs.year > rhs.year)
else if(lhs.year < rhs.year)
else
{
    and check here for months etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator <` should return a `bool` value:

```
 bool operator < (const ClassName &l, const ClassName &r) 
 {
   return
     std::tie(l.year, l.month, l.day, l.hour, l.minute, l.second, l.millisecond)
     <
     std::tie(r.year, r.month, r.day, r.hour, r.minute, r.second, r.millisecond);
 }
```

And you can use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), it wonderfully reduces the lines of code.

Comment: Thank you! what does std::tie do if you wouldnt mind explaining that would be great thanks.